# pagination in page with custom code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

How to add pagination for comments in page with custom code in Wordpress?

My code:

```
<?php
<ol class="comment-list">

<?php   
    
$comments = get_comments(array(
'number'  => '8',
'status' => 'approve',
'offset' => $offset
));

foreach( $comments as $comment ){
    echo $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content;
}
                        
?>          
    
</ol>

<?php paginate_comments_links ( array( 'prev_text'  =>  '« PREV' ,  'next_text'  =>  'NEXT »' ) ); ?>
```

I searched here for solutions, but did not find any. There are old posts from before 2014. Other codes given here do not work. I have been struggling for several hours.

Please help.